# Graph theory : How to find edges ??

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

A simple graph in which each pair of distinct vertices is joined by an edge is called a complete graph. We denote by Kn the complete graph on n vertices.
A simple bipartite graph with bipartition (X,Y) such that every vertex of X is adjacent to every vertex of Y is called a complete bipartite graph.

If |X| = m and |Y| = n, we denote this graph with Km,n.

(a) How many edges does Kn have?

(b) How many edges does Km,n have?

Comment: Can you make a start on these problems?

Comment: @GerryMyerson i got # of ways are nc2 = n(n-1)/2 edges and  So total # of edges = mn

Comment: Then you got the right answers. So, why the question?

Comment: i got the right answer after @Nicholas R. Peterson gave me the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$K_n$ has exactly one edge for each unordered pair of distinct vertices.

$K_{m,n}$ has exactly one edge for each pair $(x,y)$ of vertices such that $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.

So, if you can count those pairs, you can count the edges.

Comment: i found out for question a that you can get the edges by choosing two vertices in Kn. therefore # of ways are nc2 = n(n-1)/2 edges.

Comment: For b) km,n bipartition (x,y) therefore # of edges from 0 vertex in x to y is 'n', So total # of edges = mn

Comment: @Mora You got it!

Comment: Thank you so much that was really useful !